# Css file is not getting generated even after scss is getting compiling successfully

Tags: gruntjs

Below is my code of gruntjs css file is not getting generated even after the scss is compiled successfully with no error

I have tried using the different version and i am using the windows 8

Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),    
        concat:{
           js:{
                src: 'C:/Local_code/js/*.js',
                dest: 'C:/Local_code/src/build.js',
                reporterOutput:''
            },
            css: {
                src: 'css/*.css',
                dest: 'build/main.css'
             }
        },
        autoprefixer:{
            dist:{
              files:{
                'css/foundation.css':'css/foundation.css'
              }
            }
          },
          sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    compass: true,
                    sourceMap:true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'C:/Local-code/Scss/',
                    src: 'C:/Local-code/Scss/*.scss/',
                    dest: 'C:/Local-code/build/pratik.css',
                    ext: '.css'
                }]
            }
        },
          postcss: {
            options: {
                map: true, 
                map: {
                    inline: false, 
                    annotation: 'dist/css/maps/'
                },

                processors: [
                    require('pixrem')(),
                    //require('autoprefixer')({browsers: 'last 2 versions'}), 
                    require('cssnano')() 
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                src: 'css/*.css'
            }
        },
    })
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss'); //The “src” folder will hold your unprocessed CSS files, and PostCSS will write your compiled CSS files into the “dest” folder.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify-es');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');  

    //grunt.registerTask('concat-js', ['concat:js']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
    //grunt.registerTask('build', ['autoprefixer']);
};
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Aem Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "pratik",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "compass": "^0.1.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pixrem": "^5.0.0",
    "uglify-js": "github:mishoo/UglifyJS2#harmony"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^4.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "^3.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.9.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.3.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Expected result it should generate the valid css file in destination path.

Actual result css file i not getting generated and no error are coming.